# How to limit a jpa query

Tags: java, database, jax-rs, jpa-2.0

I want to restrict a query in jpa, that only give me the last 20 entities. How may I do?
Right now I have (This code give me all the entities in that table):

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("select u from Game u")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

> entityManager.createQuery("select u from Game u").setMaxResults(limit).setFirstResult(offset)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

```
q.setMaxResults(20);
```

With this you would limit the query to fetch only the last 20 entities.

Comment: Could you explain *why*?

Comment: because the OP needed the last 20 results

Comment: I mean, add an explanation to your answer.